# Can a router be connected to a both a subnet and a subnet inside that subnet?

Tags: ip, router, subnet, packet, mask

Can a router be connected to both a subnet 1 and a subnet 1.1 which is a subnet inside of subnet 1?

For example, can a router be connected and sent packets to subnet 223.1.17.128/25 and 223.1.17.192/28?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Yep, it's possible. But the packets will be routed through only one route with longest prefix match.

Let's guess you have router with three interfaces:

- e0 - uplink - address `192.0.2.10/24`, default gateway - `192.0.2.1`
- e1 - lan1 - `223.1.17.129/25`
- e2 - lan2 - `223.1.17.193/28`

And routing table will be seems like:

```
static 0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0 via 192.0.2.1 dev e0
connected 192.0.2.0/24 dev e0
connected 223.1.17.128/25 dev e1
connected 223.1.17.192/28 dev e2
```

Simplify the corner cases like routing to local addresses and broadcast addresses, we get following behaviour for overlapped address spaces:

- The packets to addresses `223.1.17.192-223.1.17.207` will be routed through `e2` interface.
- The packets to addresses `223.1.17.128-233.1.17.191` and `223.1.17.208-223.1.17.255` will be routed through `e1` interface.

Thus, the hosts with addresses from range `223.1.17.192-223.1.17.207`, connected to `e1` interface (that has `/25` prefix) will be in the blind spot. They won't have access through the router, only to hosts in same broadcast domain. To avoid this negative behaviour you should use something like `vrf` on the router.